# Linq Group Join with Where clause

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to implement a join in linq to entities (VB.NET). The sql would look something like this:

```
SELECT someField FROM SomeTable a
LEFT JOIN someOtherTable b ON a.Key = b.Key AND b.Name <> ''
```

This is just a small subset of the query, there are many other joins, but the issue is the where clause on the join. I can usually do this by joining on an anonymous type, but I'm not sure how to implement the b.Name <> '' in the join using the anonymous type method. For example:

```
    Return From document In dbContext.Documents
            Group Join assessorNumberRow In dbContext.AssessorNumbers
                On New With {document.DocumentId, .IsEmpty = False} Equals {assessorNumberRow.DocumentId, assessorNumberRow.AssessorNumber1}
                Into foundAssessorNumbers = Group
                From foundAssessorNumber In foundAssessorNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But this isn't going to work because the anonymous types cannot be compared because I am not quite sure how to setup the condition to make sure assessorNumberRow.Number isn't empty IN THE JOIN - not in the final where clause.

I think I could do something like this in the final where:

```
Where foundAssessorNumber Is Nothing OrElse foundAssessorNumber.Number <> string.empty.
```

but I think the syntax of including the where condition in the actual join is easier to follow rather than tacking it onto the end of the entire query.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it before, adding a `Where` extension method to the left joined entity, for example

(not used to vb.net linq syntax, so there maybe an error)

```
Return From document In dbContext.Documents
            Group Join assessorNumberRow In dbContext.AssessorNumbers.Where(Function(a) a.Number <> string.Empty))
            On ...
```

Comment: Man, I can't believe I didn't think of doing it that way. Very nice, thanks!